# Task<string> returns null always

Tags: c#, async-await

I am building an ASP.net core web api which consumes another REST endpoint internally.

Here is the code for my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EductionAPI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace EductionAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/{text}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoneyEductionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MoneyEductionController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public ActionResult<MoneyEduced> EduceFromTextAsync(string text)
        {
            MoneyEduced retVal = new MoneyEduced();
            EductionService eductionService = new EductionService(_configuration);
            string matched_text = eductionService.GetMatchedCurrencyAsync(text).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            retVal.CurrencyValue = matched_text;
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the Eduction Service

```
using EductionAPI.ConfigurationModels;
using EductionAPI.Services.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EductionAPI.Services
{
    public class EductionService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public EductionSettings _settings { get; set; }
        public EductionService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            EductionSettings eductionSettings = new EductionSettings(configuration);
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _settings = eductionSettings;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetMatchedCurrencyAsync(string text)
        {
            Task<EductionResponse> response = EduceFromTextAsync(text);
            EductionResponse autnResponse = response.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return await Task.FromResult(autnResponse.Autnresponse.responsedata.hit[0].matched_text);
        }
        public async Task<EductionResponse> EduceFromTextAsync(string text)
        {
            string url = $"http://{_settings.Hostname}:{_settings.Port}/Action=EduceFromText&Text={text}&responseFormat=simplejson";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<EductionResponse>(responseStream);
        }


    }
}
```

I know the api is getting called internally but the result is always null from my endpoint.

[image]

I am unable to understand why.

Comment: Let's avoid discussing the quality of the code here, in the comments section, as it's not the [purpose of the comments section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Instead, let's just consider that not everyone is an expert, and help them become.

Comment: The result is not `null`. You don't even get the result because a `NullReferenceException` occurs internally. I suspect that the culprit is somewhere is this fragment: `autnResponse.Autnresponse.responsedata.hit[0].matched_text`. Every dot in this fragment could return a `null` value. You should write more defensive code, and in case of unexpected events throw meaningful exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `async`/`await` wherever possible to resolve `Task` to result. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is used as a last resort when you try to consume asynchronous methods from synchronous code. Usually when you have legacy app using newer library or Nuget package.

Regarding `null exception` most likely cause is line:
`autnResponse.Autnresponse.responsedata.hit[0].matched_text;`

Try rewrite your code like it's written bellow and once `Task` result is unpacked properly, check if your `autnResponse` object has all child objects initialized properly.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EductionAPI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace EductionAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/{text}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoneyEductionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MoneyEductionController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<MoneyEduced> EduceFromTextAsync(string text)
        {
            var retVal = new MoneyEduced();
            var eductionService = new EductionService(_configuration);
            string matched_text = await eductionService.GetMatchedCurrencyAsync(text);

            retVal.CurrencyValue = matched_text;
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using EductionAPI.ConfigurationModels;
using EductionAPI.Services.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EductionAPI.Services
{
    public class EductionService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public EductionSettings _settings { get; set; }
        public EductionService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            EductionSettings eductionSettings = new EductionSettings(configuration);
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _settings = eductionSettings;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetMatchedCurrencyAsync(string text)
        {
            EductionResponse autnResponse = await EduceFromTextAsync(text);
            // Line bellow is most likely cause for null exception
            return autnResponse.Autnresponse.responsedata.hit[0].matched_text;
        }
        public async Task<EductionResponse> EduceFromTextAsync(string text)
        {
            string url = $"http://{_settings.Hostname}:{_settings.Port}/Action=EduceFromText&Text={text}&responseFormat=simplejson";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<EductionResponse>(responseStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue using the following modifications to the Controller and the Service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EductionAPI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace EductionAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/{text}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoneyEductionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MoneyEductionController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public MoneyEduced EduceFromText(string text)
        {
            var retVal = new MoneyEduced();
            var eductionService = new EductionService(_configuration);
            string matched_text = eductionService.GetMatchedCurrency(text);

            retVal.CurrencyValue = matched_text;
            retVal.ConvertCurrencyToInt ();
            retVal.CalculateTax();
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Service.

```
using EductionAPI.ConfigurationModels;
using EductionAPI.Services.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EductionAPI.Services
{
    public class EductionService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public EductionSettings _settings { get; set; }
        public EductionService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            EductionSettings eductionSettings = new EductionSettings(configuration);
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _settings = eductionSettings;
        }
        public string GetMatchedCurrency(string text)
        {
            EductionResponse _eductionResponse = EduceFromTextAsync(text);
            // Line bellow is most likely cause for null exception
            return CleanCurrency(_eductionResponse.autnresponse.responsedata.hit[0].matched_text).TrimEnd();
        }
        public EductionResponse EduceFromTextAsync(string text)
        {
            string url = $"http://{_settings.Hostname}:{_settings.Port}/Action=EduceFromText&Text={text}&responseFormat=simplejson";
            var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            EductionResponse retval = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EductionResponse>(jsonString);
            return retval;
        }
        private string CleanCurrency(string currency)
        {
            string remove_dollar_sign = currency.Replace("$", "");
            string remove_comma_sign = remove_dollar_sign.Replace(",", "");
            return remove_comma_sign;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not see any point in "bubbling up" await. I rather used `GetAwaiter()` and `GetResult()` to solve it.

The answer provided previously did not work. Hence, I sought to resolve it using the above approach.

Comment: Idea using `async`/`await` is to release active system thread for the duration of I/O request, so same thread can serve another request, instead of sitting and waiting for I/O to finish. By using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` you lock the thread, so server needs more resources/threads to serve multiple requests.